# WebStorm debugging configuration with authentication

Tags: node.js, debugging, authentication, passport.js, webstorm

Is it possible to set up a debug configuration for NodeJS in WebStorm that would get me beyond the Passport authentication. So that I can test the functionality of pages in the browser and it would send me back to my breakpoints in WebStorm (as I would for debugging an ordinary site that didn't require login authentication)?

When I edit my NodeJS Debug Configuration maybe? Ideally, I could (er, would know how to...) set

```
email = xxxx
password = xxxx
```

as Environment Variables (or whatever) so that the Passport local authentication strategy is satisfied. And I can go on to inspect the code and functionality that comes *after* authentication.

Comment: you can set environment variables in your Node.js run configuration, 'environment variables' filed

Comment: Thanks, @lena, I know that environment variables can be set. I'm looking for specifics about how to circumvent the need to login when debugging other things.